# SQL Server errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Code:

```
Declare @ParmDefinition Nvarchar(1000),
        @St Nvarchar(500),
        @TTable varchar(30) 

Set @TTable='[0Detail]'

Declare @TTempStore Table (
                        Iden Int,
                        Row_ Int,
                        Accs_iden int,
                        Am_Bed Money,
                        Am_Bes Money,
                        Doc_No Decimal(15,0),
                        Desc_ Nvarchar(500),
                        Checked bit,
                        Error_ int)

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@alaki table(Iden Int,
                                     Row_ Int,
                                     Accs_iden int,
                                     Am_Bed Money,
                                     Am_Bes Money,
                                     Doc_No Decimal(15,0),
                                     Desc_ Nvarchar(500),Checked bit,Error_ int)   OUTPUT '

Set @St = N' Select * into @alaki from  '+@TTable

EXECUTE sp_executesql @St, @ParmDefinition, @alaki = @TTempStore 

SELECT * FROM @TTempStore
```

Errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '@alaki'.

Answer (score 0):

You should post a minimal working sample for us to be able to help you, remember that next time.

Why not declare the table with `#TTempStore` ?

```
Declare @St Nvarchar(500),@TTable varchar(30) 

Set @TTable='[0Detail]'

create table #TTempStore (

                    Iden Int,
                    Row_ Int,
                    Accs_iden int,
                    Am_Bed Money,
                    Am_Bes Money,
                    Doc_No Decimal(15,0),
                    Desc_ Nvarchar(500),
                    Checked bit,
                    Error_ int)


 Set @St=N' Select * into #TTempStore from '+@TTable
 EXECUTE @St
 Select * from #TTempStore
 drop table #TTempStore --here you can leave the table if you have more things to do
```

I haven't tested it, but it should point you in the right direction. If you need I can probably make a sql fiddle later.

Answer (score 0):

Could the `@TTable` value be different every time? If it's always going to be `[0Detail]` then you don't need dynamic SQL. However, here is a dynamic SQL solution to your problem:

```
Declare @St Nvarchar(500),@TTable varchar(30)

Set @TTable='[0Detail]'

Declare @TTempStore Table (

                    Iden Int,
                    Row_ Int,
                    Accs_iden int,
                    Am_Bed Money,
                    Am_Bes Money,
                    Doc_No Decimal(15,0),
                    Desc_ Nvarchar(500),
                    Checked bit,
                    Error_ int)

Set @St=N' Select * from  '+@TTable

INSERT INTO @TTempStore
EXECUTE (@St)

Select * from @TTempStore
```